# CakePHP $this->Form->end('button text'); on same line with something

Tags: cakephp

I have a simple cakephp form and would like for the 'save translation' button to be to the LEFT of a link which cancels and returns the user to the index, but I can't seem to get it working. It always puts the cancel link below the button.

Code I have now:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end('Save Translation'); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $html->link('Cancel', array('action' => 'index')); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Code I've tried:

```
echo $this->Form->end('Save Translation',array('label'=>'Save Translation','div' => false));
```

Comment: Can you post the output and your expected output? This sounds like a CSS thing more than a Cake thing, because you could just `echo` it right before cancel..

Comment: also $html->link should be $this-Html->link (cake1.3 and above)

Comment: @jeremyharris I don't have any css just yet(created my own default.ctp, just didn't give it css), trying to get the main functionality working. Will edit to add an image with output i'm getting. Can't post an image D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create();
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
    echo $this->Form->submit('Submit', 
        array('after' => $this->Html->link('Cancel', array('action' => 'index')))
    );
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! :) Also, you can't do ANYTHING on here without  rep, it's frustrating. XD